# Print an error message without "Error detected while processing function"

Tags: functions, error, errorformat

If I type:

`:echoerr "test error"`

I simply get the message printed (with red background):

> `test error`

However, inside a function:

```
function! Printerror()
  echoerr "test error"
endfunction
```

I get additional (and in this particular case) unwanted extra lines:

> ```
> Error detected while processing function Printerror:
> line    1:
> test error
> Press ENTER or type command to continue
> ```

How can I supress the additional lines produced in a function?

Comment: See also `: h hit-enter` and `:h cmdheight`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is described in the manual:

> If you just want a highlighted message use `:echohl`.
>   And to get a beep: `:exe "normal \<Esc>"`

Thus:

```
function! PrintError(msg) abort
    execute 'normal! \<Esc>'
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echomsg a:msg
    echohl None
endfunction
```

Comment: Hmm, why doesn't `:echohl "foo"` work in command mode?

Comment: @TomHale, because you didn't read `:help :echohl`. And it's "command-line mode", not "command mode".